# How to use fraction for PSTricks's coordinates?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Definitions of functions
\def\f(#1){4-#1*#1/3}
\def\g(#1){#1*#1/4}  

% Shade the area bounded by the two graphs in [-1,2]
\fill[blue!30] 
plot[domain=-1:2] (\x,{\f(\x)})--(2,{\g(2)})--
plot[domain=2:-1] (\x,{\g(\x)})--(-1,0)--cycle;

% Draw axes
\draw[->] (-3,0)--(3.5,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-.5)--(0,4.5) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[dashed] 
%(2,{\f(2)})--(2,0) node[below]{$2$} 
%(-1,{\f(-1)})--(-1,0) node[below]{$-1$};
(2,8/3)--(2,0) node[below]{$2$}        %% <<<---
(-1,11/3)--(-1,0) node[below]{$-1$};   %% <<<---
% Draw the two graphs
\draw plot[domain=-3:3] (\x,{\f(\x)});
\draw plot[domain=-3:3] (\x,{\g(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-calculate}
\begin{document} 
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-3.2,-1.2)(4.2,5)
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!30,linestyle=none]{%
\psplot{-1}{2}{(x^2)/4}
\psplot{2}{-1}{4-(x^2)/3}
 }
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-3,-1)(4,5)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\psplot{-3}{3}{(x^2)/4}
\psplot{-3}{3}{4-(x^2)/3}
\psLineSegments[linestyle=dashed](-1,0)(-1,\pscalculate{11/3})(2,0)(2,\pscalculate{8/3})   %% <<<---
\psxTick(-1){$-1$}
\psxTick(2){$2$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to use fraction for PSTricks's coordinates ??

Comment: Who is “we” and what is the problem?

Comment: @HenriMenke I guess "we" refers to the users and I think that the question is why pstricks does not parse coordinates in the way Ti*k*Z does. I think that's a valid question.

Comment: @marmot I see.  As far as I know https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/ is better suited for questions involving guessing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `(*{postfix constant} {infix expression in x})`

  `(*-1 11/3)` is equal to TikZ `(-1,11/3)`.

  Actually you can do more complicated for example `(*{0 1 sub} {11/3+0*x})` because the last can be any expression in `x`.
- `(+{infix constant},{infix expression in x})`

  `(+-1,11/3)` is equal to TikZ `(-1,11/3)`.

  Actually you can do more complicated for example `(+0-1,11/3+0*x)` because the last can be any expression in `x`.

I recommend to always use `{...}` for both abscissa and ordinate because it is the safest way. The current parser is not clever enough.

## Summary:

For our reference in the future, let me write the summary as follows. The last one has not been implemented yet. Please contact the maintainer if you want to request the last feature. :-)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
% the trailing spaces are intentionally added
\def\f{x/2 }
\def\F{2*y }
\pstVerb{/I2P {AlgParser cvx exec} def}% infix to postfix

\def\point[#1](#2){\pscircle*[linecolor=#1](#2){4pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](9,5)
    % postfix constant and infix f(x)
    \point[red](*{1 1 add} \f)              % (2,f(2))=(2,1)

    % infix constant and infix f(x)
    \point[green](+8/2,\f)                  % (4,f(4))=(4,2)

    % infix F(y) and postfix constant
    \point[blue](**\F 1 2 add)              % (F(3),3)=(6,3)

    % Unfortunately,
    % infix F(y) and infix constant
    %\point[black](++\F,8/2)                % (F(4),4)=(8,4)
    % has not been implemented yet  
    % but we can use I2P as follows
    \point[black](**\F {(8/2) I2P})         % (F(4),4)=(8,4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Until now, I just know that coordinates can be modified complexly.

Comment: @chishimotoji: See my summary. If you need the last feature that has not been implemented yet, please kindly ask HV. He may be interested to implement it. The ubiquitously needed `I2P` macro should be exposed as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to read your mind. Probably what you are looking for is something like the following.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\f{x^2/4 }% adding a trailing space is a good practice here
\def\g{4-x^2/3 }
\def\G{sqrt(12-3*y) }% the inverse of the left part of g(x)
\pstVerb{/I2P {AlgParser cvx exec} def}% infix to postfix
\begin{document} 
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-3.2,-1.2)(4.2,5)
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!30,linestyle=none]{
    \psplot{-1}{2}{\f}
    \psplot{2}{-1}{\g}}
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-3,-1)(4,5)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\psplot{-3}{3}{\f}
\psplot{-3}{3}{\g}
\psLineSegments[linestyle=dashed](-1,0)(*-1 \g)(2,0)(**\G {(8/3) I2P})
\psxTick(-1){$-1$}
\psxTick(2){$2$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \psLineSegments[linestyle=dashed](-1,0)(*-1 \g)(2,0)(*2 \g) !!!

Comment: @chishimotoji: Yes. I know. I just wanted to let you know that you can do the inverse, i.e., abscissa is a function of y.