# Why one must use two \psframe for clip?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-plot}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[algebraic,saveNodeCoors](-1.5,-1.5)(2.5,2)
    \psset{linewidth=0.5pt,unit=1.25cm,plotstyle=curve}
    \psclip{\psframe[framearc=0.1](-1,-1)(2,1.5)}% <<-- ,linestyle=none
\psaxes[Dx=1,dx=1,Dy=1,dy=1,subticks=2,subticksize=1,labels=none,ticksize=2pt -2pt]{->}(0,0)(-1,-1)(3,2)
    \def\f{x^4-x}
    \def\g{x/(sqrt(x^2+1))}
    \psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
    \pstInterFF{\f}{\g}{0}{M_1}
    \pstInterFF{\f}{\g}{1}{M_0}
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,opacity=.5,linestyle=none]{%
    \psplot{N-M_0.x}{N-M_1.x}{\f}
    \psplot{N-M_1.x}{N-M_0.x}{\g}}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-1}{1.5}{\f}
    \psplot[linecolor=green]{-1}{2}{\g}
    \rput(M_0){\psframebox{}}
    \endpsclip
    % \psframe[framearc=0.1](-1,-1)(2,1.5)   % <<--
    \rput(1,-0.6){\tiny $y=x^4-x$}
    \rput(0.5,1.2){\tiny $ \displaystyle \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$}
    \psline{->}(0.6,0.95)(0.8,0.65)
\uput{3pt}[180](-1,0){$-1$}
\uput{3pt}[-90](0,-1){$-1$}
\uput{3pt}[0](2,0){$2$}
\uput{3pt}[90](0,1.5){$1.5$}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If

```
\psclip{\psframe[framearc=0.1,linestyle=none](-1,-1)(2,1.5)}
...
\psframe[framearc=0.1](-1,-1)(2,1.5)
```

the output is correct

[image]

To fill color between two function, you can see this:

[How to fill color between function and circle in the following?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472902/how-to-fill-color-between-function-and-circle-in-the-following)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is important to note here is that, from the [`pstricks`](//ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/pstricks) (section **28 Clipping**),

> The command
>
> ```
> \psclip{<graphics>} ... {} \endpsclip
> ```
>
> sets the *clipping path* to the path drawn by the `<graphics>` object(s), until the
> `\endpsclip` command is reached.

I've added my own emphasis here to "clipping path", which excludes the *stroke* (and its associated width). You'll see this when you increase the `linewidth` to some obscene value (say, `10pt`) within the `<graphics>` element:

[image]

That's why it's also suggested to use `linestyle=none` and, consequently, reset the same frame after the fact in order to achieve a nice overlay. The first example in the documentation does the same:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(10,10)
  \psclip{%
    \pscustom[linestyle=none]{%
      \psplot{.5}{4}{2 x div}% 2/x
      \lineto(4,4)}
    \pscustom[linestyle=none]{%
      \psplot{0}{3}{3 x x mul 3 div sub}% 3-(x^2)/3
      \lineto(0,0)}}
    \psframe*[linecolor=gray](0,0)(4,4)% Sets the shaded fill
  \endpsclip
  \psplot[linewidth=1.5pt]{.5}{4}{2 x div}% Redraw 2/x
  \psplot[linewidth=1.5pt]{0}{3}{3 x x mul 3 div sub}% Redraw 3-(x^2)/3
  \psaxes(4,4)% Axes
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

So, in essence, the "shape" is used to clip and this excludes the stroke, which may have to be redrawn for whatever effect is needed.

Answer (score 4):

I need only *one* `\psclip` for the blue curve. The filling can be done with `\pscustom`. You already have the intesection points:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\def\f{x^4-x}
\def\g{x/(sqrt(x^2+1))}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic,saveNodeCoors](-1.5,-1.5)(2.5,2)
    \psset{linewidth=0.5pt,unit=1.25cm,plotstyle=curve}
    \psaxes[subticks=2,subticksize=1,labels=none,ticksize=2pt -2pt]{->}(0,0)(-1,-1)(2,1.5)[2,0][1.5,90]
    \psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
    \pstInterFF{\f}{\g}{0}{M_1}
    \pstInterFF{\f}{\g}{1}{M_0}
    \psdot[dotstyle=square,dotsize=0.25](M_0)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,opacity=0.5,linestyle=none]{%
        \psplot{N-M_0.x}{N-M_1.x}{\f}
        \psplot{N-M_1.x}{N-M_0.x}{\g}}
    \psclip{\psframe[framearc=0.1](-1,-1)(2,1.5)}
      \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-1}{1.5}{\f}
    \endpsclip
    \psplot[linecolor=green]{-1}{2}{\g}
    \rput(1,-0.6){\tiny $y=x^4-x$}
    \rput(0.5,1.2){\tiny $ \displaystyle \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$}
    \psline{->}(0.6,0.95)(0.8,0.65)
    \uput{3pt}[180](-1,0){$-1$}
    \uput{3pt}[-90](0,-1){$-1$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Something reminds me of a recent question of mine ahahah :-) +1

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, particularly also because the OP only uses a single/one `\psclip`, not two. You've removed the final `\psframe` that redraws the frame to nicely limit the polynomial drawings being overlaid with the frame. Here's a close-up of your top-left corner - [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpC3w.png) - which, instead, should resemble [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A79mG.png).

Comment: Sure, the clipping path has no linewidth, hence the curve goes into the middle of the frame line. If you do not like it, then draw the frame a second time after the clipping.